# Cumbersome generics declaration in a huge Java classes hierarchy

Tags: java, generics

I have basically two types of each entity in my project which are distinguisched only by specifying the parent catalog type in the class generics declaration. Catalogs iteself are declared with generics as they can have links to a specific old catalog of the same type.

```
abstract class AbstractCatalog<T extends AbstractCatalog<T>> {

    public abstract T getOld();
}

class Catalog1 extends AbstractCatalog<Catalog1> {

    @Override
    public Catalog1 getOld() { ... }
}

class Catalog2 extends AbstractCatalog<Catalog2> {

    @Override
    public Catalog2 getOld() { ... }
}
```

So far so good but the problem is that it becomes really cumbersome if I add some entities that must contain a link to a catalog of a certain type.

For instance,

```
abstract class AbstractCatalogHistory<C extends AbstractCatalog<C>, E extends AbstractHistoryEntry<C, E>> {

    public abstract Set<E> getEntries();
}

abstract class AbstractHistoryEntry<C extends AbstractCatalog<C>, E AbstractHistoryEntry<C, E>> {

    public abstract E getPrior();
}

class Cat1HistoryEntry extends AbstractHistoryEntry<Catalog1, Cat1HistoryEntry> {

    @Override
    public Cat1HistoryEntry getPrior() { ... }
}

class Cat2HistoryEntry extends AbstractHistoryEntry<Catalog2, Cat2HistoryEntry> {

    @Override
    public Cat2HistoryEntry getPrior() { ... }
}

class Catalog1History extends AbstractCatalogHistory<Catalog1, Cat1HistoryEntry> {

    @Override
    public Set<Cat1HistoryEntry> getEntries() { ... }
}

class Catalog2History extends AbstractCatalogHistory<Catalog2, Cat2HistoryEntry> {

    @Override
    public Set<Cat2HistoryEntry> getEntries() { ... }
}
```

so it gets much more difficult to get idea of what's going on while looking at such a hierarchy. This example is by no means complete and I have dozens of types that should be nested within those I provided above.

What I'm trying to do by doing this is to take advantage of type safe code which can be verified at compile time. But at the same time such a code becomes completely messy as I have to specify longer generics chains while adding new types to the hierarchy.

Is there a way to handle such generics explosion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't make it entirely clear *why* you need to have separate classes for `Catalog1` and `Catalog2`, but let's assume this is set.

However, even so I see no reason why everything else referencing these catalogs would require this kind of duplication. If you just want to make sure it's associated with the right catalog type, then this is the only generic parameter you should really need:

```
class CatalogHistory<C extends AbstractCatalog<C>> {
    public Set<HistoryEntry<C>> getEntries();
}

class HistoryEntry<C extends AbstractCatalog<C>> {
    public HistoryEntry<C> getPrior();
}
```

But what if you are actually doing different things in e.g. `Cat1HistoryEntry` and `Cat2HistoryEntry` so you need the separate classes? In that case you can obviously not get around having the abstract base class and two concrete implementations, but I see no need to introduce generic types and then nail them down to the concrete types the way you do:

```
abstract class AbstractHistoryEntry<C extends AbstractCatalog<C>> {

    public abstract AbstractHistoryEntry<C> getPrior();
}

class Cat1HistoryEntry extends AbstractHistoryEntry<Catalog1> {

    @Override
    public Cat1HistoryEntry getPrior() { ... }
}

class Cat2HistoryEntry extends AbstractHistoryEntry<Catalog2> {

    @Override
    public Cat2HistoryEntry getPrior() { ... }
}
```

There are a few things going on here. First, consider `AbstractHistoryEntry`. If you have one of those, you are working on a generic level and should not care that `getPrior` returns this or that concrete subtype - all you need to know is that it returns another `AbstractHistoryEntry` object referencing the same catalog.

If you have a concrete `Cat1HistoryEntry` reference however, you can still get the full type safety of getting another `Cat1HistoryEntry` out of `getPrior` thanks to the covariance of return types in Java.

Now it gets slightly more complicated - Let's try to pull the same trick with `AbstractCatalogHistory`:

```
abstract class AbstractCatalogHistory<C extends AbstractCatalog<C>> {

    public abstract Set<? extends AbstractHistoryEntry<C>> getEntries();
}

class Catalog1History extends AbstractCatalogHistory<Catalog1> {

    @Override
    public Set<Cat1HistoryEntry> getEntries() { ... }
}

class Catalog2History extends AbstractCatalogHistory<Catalog2> {

    @Override
    public Set<Cat2HistoryEntry> getEntries() { ... }
}
```

As you can see, both concrete subclasses still return a set of the concrete  types `Cat1HistoryEntry` and `Cat2HistoryEntry`. The abstract base type now needs to express a common supertype for those sets so that you can work with the result in a generic way. This is done by introducing covariance.

***Setters***

Setters complicate the matter a bit. Basically, if you have a generic container / collection like a `List<T>` or an `AbstractCatalogHistory<C>`, and you want to allow both adding and retrieving items, you can no longer have variance in the item type if you want type safety.

For example, if you had a setter in `AbstractCatalogHistory<C>` which allows you to add any `AbstractHistoryEntry<C>` items to the history, then you have a problem, because if your `AbstractCatalogHistory<C>` is actually a `Catalog1History` then you only want `Cat1HistoryEntry` items in there!

This is the same problem as with generic lists: A `List<Cat>` is not a `List<Mammal>` because you can add an elephant to a `List<Mammal>`, but you shouldn't be able to add an elephant to a `List<Cat>`.

If you insist that a history for `Catalog1` must consist only of `Cat1HistoryEntry` items, then a solution would be to only add a setter to `Catalog1History`, and none to `AbstractCatalogHistory<C>`. That way the generic classes would only be used for reading the history, not writing it.

However, going back to the beginning of my answer: If you don't actually don't need the dual concrete classes, the solution remains very simple. Unfortunately you still didn't explain why or if you need those. If all you really want is the `Catalog1` / `Catalog2` distinction, and you don't actually need a different implementation for e.g. `Cat1HistoryEntry` and `Cat2HistoryEntry`, then the following should suffice:

```
class CatalogHistory<C extends AbstractCatalog<C>> {
    public Set<HistoryEntry<C>> getEntries();
    public void addEntry(HistoryEntry<C> entry);
}

class HistoryEntry<C extends AbstractCatalog<C>> {
    public HistoryEntry<C> getPrior();
    public void setPrior(HistoryEntry<C> prior);
}
```

Comment: Medo42, thanks! The only thing I cannot figure out is how to implement setters in a type safe manner.